# How to get "state" value from callback url facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I have a issue related to facebook login url and i need your help.

i am creting login url using PHP SDK and i have set the state = 1, and now i need to get the state value from call back url. i am unable to get this.

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
                        'scope' => 'publish_stream,offline_access,email,user_location,user_birthday',
                        'redirect_uri' => $redirectUrl,
                        'state' => '1'
));
```

Callback Url will be

```
https://apps.facebook.com/myapp_namespace/?state=1&code=************
```

how can i get this back..

I have tried $_GET and $_REQUEST... I have decode $_GET['signed_request] also... but get nothing.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is returned in `$_GET['state']`.  Since you didn't really give us much more info, I assume that wall all you needed to know.

Comment: Hi Austin thanks for your attention... the call back url will be... https://apps.facebook.com/myapp_namespace/?state=1&code=****

Comment: I have tried $_GET and $_REQUEST... I have decode $_GET['signed_request] also... but get nothing

Comment: yes you r rt.. when i tried to create a login url with my Canvas page url it redirect it to index.php but i have set countdown.php in the site url... thats y i unable to get it... I got $_GET['state'] in countdown.php by setting site url in login url insted of canvas url..  Thanks again...

Comment: Not a problem, but for future reference, the more code you provide, the better help you'll receive.  For example, if you had included how you set `$redirectUrl` or maybe some code you had on the page it redirected to.  Just a thought, glad you have it working now.